# How to get a query sorted by a formula of two columns in dbflow library?

Tags: android, database, dbflow

I am working with dbflow library and I have a "Player" table that has two columns "wins" and "losses".
I want to get all of "Player" rows sorting by (wins*3-losses) in descending order.
I have tried this:

```
playerList = SQLite.select().from(Player.class).orderBy(Player_Table.x01Wins.times(3).minus(Player_Table.x01Losses), false).queryList();
```

But it has an error.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please add the error message to the question.

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'orderBy(com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.language.operator, boolean)'